How to add a string between XML tags which value is obtained from a text file ?? (bash)
I have some XML tags names stored in a text file, an XML file in which i want to add the same string as another value for those tags.
XML Tags File :
name1
name2
name3

XML File :
<Category name="name1">value1 value2 value3 ...</Category>
<Category name="name2">value1 value2 value3 ...</Category>
<Category name="name3">value1 value2 value3 ...</Category>

I tried dozens of "sed", "cat" commands but quite a pain in the a*s ... I was expecting that, after I used the script/command, the XML File would look like this :
<Category name="name1">VALUE4 value1 value2 value3 ...</Category>
<Category name="name2">VALUE4 value1 value2 value3 ...</Category>
<Category name="name3">VALUE4 value1 value2 value3 ...</Category>

(VALUE4 is the string I want to add, and I want to add it as the first value !)
Thanks in advance for the help !
LePousson

Welcome on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not a free coding service, it is a website where you can find help with your own code. Please show your code and explain what is wrong with it such that we can help you fixing it. You could also take a look at the help center and especially at the asking section.

The best way is to use a xml library to modify the file, not an editing tool like sed.  XML is not regular and text editors are meant for regular text.

The tool for this job is XSLT.
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSLTransform"
               version="3.0"
               expand-text="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="tags" 
                select="tokenize(unparsed-text('tags-file.txt'))"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Category[@name=$tags]/text()">
    <xsl:text>VALUE4 {.}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>

I've used XSLT 3.0 here. 1.0 processors are more widely available but that makes the code a lot more verbose.
Don't try to do this with text-based tools. As you've discovered, it's a pain to get it right, and when you succeed, your code will fail as soon as someone supplies an XML file that's very slightly different from the one you tested on.

Thanks Michael for answering ... But I'm damn a noob with manipulating XML files (except manually of course !!).
Could you help me a bit with the syntax of "xsltproc" to apply this script to my xml file ??

I tried to do xsltproc sheet.xslt file.xml but I get a parsing error for the sheet file on line 5 ... What should I do ??

Either find someone who still knows how to code in XSLT 1.0 (I last used it twenty years ago) or download an XSLT 3.0 processor such as Saxon (my company's product).

unfortunately, i can't really understand all that stuf, but i can understand that you have no time for that... I'll keep searching and parying for someone who can really help !

My preferred approach in answering this kind of question is to point people in the right direction rather than taking them by the hand and walking them to their final destination. That's partly because my time is limited, but also because I think it's important that you don't implement code that you have blindly copied without understanding it. And also because I have no idea of your overall project requirements or constraints, so recommending a technology that's new to you has to be very tentative.

Also, while XSLT is the way I and many others would do it, it's not the only option. The most important part of my response is: don't try to manipulate XML as text; always use XML-aware tools. We see so many people on SO who get themselves into a terrible mess by ignoring that advice.

i'm not ignoring your advice but i'm totally new to all that stuff, and leaving me here in the middle of nowhere will not help me ... And just for you to know, even when I see some part of codes someone would have created for me, i'm always trying to understand it, all the time !! But anyway, as I can't understand and have no time to understand it, i won't be able to use XSLT for now ... If you happen to decide to help me a bit more, I'd be very happy and so grateful ... It's now up to you !
